# Unable to import CNTK in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, cntk

Every time I go to import cntk in my python environment I get "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

My environment is set up correctly, and I even get the cntk auto complete when writing code, but whenever I run the project it always fails on the first line.

I am completely at wits end trying to figure this out because I have followed every step of the tutorials for CNTK and the the [github ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/969) for this problem is still open which is absolutely no help.

My python path is  C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages;F:\cntkInstall\envs\cntk-py34\Lib\site-packages

out of sheer desperation I just started adding anything remotely python related to the path to see if I could get that to work. Still nothing. please help!

EDIT: this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages\cntk\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import ops
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages\cntk\ops\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import sequence
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages\cntk\ops\sequence\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ...utils import sanitize_input, get_data_type, typemap
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages\cntk\utils\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .. import cntk_py
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 21, in <module>
    _cntk_py = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\Lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_cntk_py')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\cntk-py35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your problem can be resolved by launching visual studio from the command line. In particular you need to activate the environment in which cntk was installed from the command line. After the environment is activated, launch visual studio from that environment via the `devenv` command. This way visual studio picks up the correct value for PYTHONPATH.